# If I have an open tab with some page, can I find out where did I found link to that page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

If I have an open tab with some page, can I find out where did I found link to that page?

I want answers like:

- You opened this tab from page XXX
- You pasted URL in address bar manually

Is there an extension for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it crudely using the **referrer** (if present).

1. `Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools`
2. `Network -> Scroll to the top item -> Select it`
3. `Request Headers -> Referrer:` **the link you came from here**

---

For **Firefox** there is an extension called [FromWheretoWhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fromwheretowhere/) that shows the full history of where each link came from.

It's [explained in detail](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/05/18/improve-firefoxs-history-with-from-where-to-where/) by Ghacks.

Comment: Good. I thought about that, but I knew that Network tab needs page reload to work. But I have tried and saw that page reload preserves Referer header. Thanks.